# How to do I remove highlights from certain code lines in netbeans 8.2?

Tags: layout, netbeans, editor

I'm new to netbeans, and I'd like to know if there's a way to remove the highlights shown in the picture. I already tried to turn off all highlights from Tools-> Editor -> Highlights
this is the ->Pic

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found it, will share for future reference:
Tools->Options->Fonts and colors-> Highlights->Guarded Block.
Change the background color to inherited.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the gray highlight? You have a JFrameForm, a Frame on Netbeans Designer right? If yes, you can not remove that highlight. It means it is auto-generated code. when u set actionPerform listener to jtextfield it auto-generated the code for it. You can fill it but not change its "format". 
One way to have less auto-generated code, is to delete any listeners assigned throu the designer view, and write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Those highlights will never go away, because they tell you that you can't edit in those lines because it's generated code and due to a license issue you can't edit generated code in freeware